# "no input file specified" - .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, ce-cache

I'm in the process of migrating my sites to Media Temple.

I need to change the htaccess file and add a '?' to successfully remove the 'index.php' from the URL. Without it I get "No input file specified"

This works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But i'm also running CE Cache, static caching.

How would I edit the static cache handler to do the same?

```
#------------------- remove trailing slash -------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

#------------------- index.php -------------------
#strip index.php from the URL if that is all that is given
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,NS,L,QSA]
#strip index.php/* from the URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/index\.php/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

#------------------- CE Cache Static Driver -------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !ACT|URL [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/ce_cache/242d7a/static%{REQUEST_URI}/index\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /_static_cache_handler.php%{REQUEST_URI}/index\.html [L,QSA]

#------------------- EE -------------------
#rewrite all non-image/js/css urls back to index.php if they are not files or directories
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I had the exact same experience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This generally has to do with PHP being connected to Apache via FastCGI, rather than mod_php. When this is the case, an extra ? is needed in the rewrites to EE's index.php:

From

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

This did it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #------------------- remove trailing slash -------------------
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

    #------------------- index.php -------------------
    #strip index.php from the URL if that is all that is given
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,NS,L,QSA]
    #strip index.php/* from the URL
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/index\.php/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

    #------------------- CE Cache Static Driver -------------------
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !ACT|URL [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST [NC]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/ce_cache/242d7a/static%{REQUEST_URI}/index\.html -f [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) /_static_cache_handler.php?%{REQUEST_URI}/index\.html [L,QSA]

    #------------------- EE -------------------
    #rewrite all non-image/js/css urls back to index.php if they are not files or directories
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Now only the home page works and I can't get to the control panel. Still having issues.

Comment: Is your system folder named "system"? If not, change this line to have the name of your system folder: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system [NC]

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to change "system" to the folder that I have renamed for my EE install. That fixed all issues.