# No input file specified on staging server

Tags: error

My site works fine locally and works fine at a dev installation. When loading it onto a network solutions hosting account, I get "No input file specified." on every page but the home page. Both dev and staging are running php as a cgi script so not sure why the error there.

Feel free to take a peek at [staging.imagenational.com](http://staging.imagenational.com)

Comment: Sounds like an environment issue not necessarily relating to ExpressionEngine. I would check that you can run a plain old PHP page, if that fails check the htaccess file (remove it for testing), and finally troubleshoot the EE app if needed.

Comment: Even went so far as to run the expressionengine environment test script they have. Everything checked out 100% on it. I've got a phpinfo script link [here](http://staging.imagenational.com/phpinfo.php)

Comment: When I hit that page, I get a working site.

Comment: the homepage works.. just not any sub page.

Comment: Yep, definitely htaccess related, looks like the answer below might clear things up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at my comment on this post:

["no input file specified" - .htaccess](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11672/no-input-file-specified-htaccess/13376#13376)

Might be the same issue: if so, you need to add a ? to the RewriteRule (to index.php) in your htaccess, for example:

From

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: We posted this at the same time. Your answer is better and was exactly what I was referring to.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that NetworkSolutions usually has some funky issues if you do not include `RewriteBase /` in your rule

Comment: @JustinKimbrell great. This issue used to drive me nuts, because it seemed random--until I learned it was a FastCGI vs mod_php issue. Now, at least I always know there's a straightforward reason why it happens.

Answer (score 4):

I have ran into the same issue on MediaTemple and have fixed it by modifying the .htaccess file. For me, my old base .htaccess references index.php and was missing a '?' after it. First place I would check is .htaccess and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

For further clarity and thoroughness, I had to engineer another approach-based solution. As an added bonus, the shared hosting environment we had to use was forced to use FastCGI, and on top of that wouldn't allow us to modify any CGI or PHP configurations. Really unhelpful I know.

As has been made clear by other answers and discussions, the problem seems to be that when using a CGI-based implementation of PHP, the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable is not available, but it is unfortunately required by ExpressionEngine when trying to route requests, specifically when trying to navigate without the pesky `index.php` string being present in the URL.

So in the end, what worked for me was this 3 step 'custom' approach:

1. First, in `ExpressionEngine > CP Home > Admin > System Administration > Output And Debugging`, I set **Force URL query strings** to **No**.
2. Next, as mentioned in previous answers, I changed the `.htaccess` directive from `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]` **to** `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]` (extra ? after index.php).
3. Finally, I added this piece of custom PHP code to the top of site root's `index.php` file to "force" the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable into accurate existence:

   ```
   <?php

       $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
       $pos = strpos($path, '?');
       if ($pos !== false)
           $path = substr($path, 0, $pos);
       $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $path;

       /**
        * ExpressionEngine - by EllisLab
          ...
          ...
   ```

I hope this helps someone! I really pulled my hair out trying to find somewhat more elegant solutions!